# Is it possible to change the variance of a base class/trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, variance

I would like to derive from Scala's immutable Map. It is defined as such:

```
trait Map[A, +B]
```

Unfortunately, my implementation needs to be invariant in B. I tried the following, but without success:

```
def +(kv : (A, B)) : MyMap[A, B] = { ... }

override def +[B1 >: B](kv : (A, B1)) : MyMap[A, B1] =
    throw new IllegalArgumentException()
```

Maybe there is a trick with `@uncheckedVariance`?

Comment: Maybe you could use a member map instead of deriving?

Comment: Also, why does it need to be invariant?  I thought (I don't know much Scala though) the only time you need invariance is if it can be both a source and a sink, but maps are immutable so it can't be a sink.

Comment: I want to implement a bi-directional Map. Not a big deal if I implement Map, and just delegate to the two internal Maps defining forward and backward mapping, but I need invariance in that case.

Comment: Maybe you could have a light interface for BiMap (mostly "modify" methods that returns new BiMap), not extending Map, and give full access to the internal, immutable maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of covariance altogether would of course be unsound, and is not allowed. 
Given `m: Map[A, String]`, and `v : Any`, you can do `val mm : Map[A, Any] = m + v`. This is what `Map` definition says, and all implementors must follow. Your class may be invariant, but it must implement the full covariant interface of Map.

Now redefining `+` to throw an error is a different story (not very sound yet). The problem with your new `+` method is that after generics erasure, it has the same signature than the other `+` method. There is a trick: add in implicit parameter, so that you have two parameters in the signature, which makes it different from the first one.

```
def +(kv : (A,B))(implicit useless: A <:< A) : MyMap[A,B]
```

(it doesn't really matter what implicit parameter you're looking for, as long as one is found. `implicit useless: Ordering[String]` works just as well)

Doing that, you have the usual problem with overloading. If you add a B without the compiler knowing it to be so, the failing method will be called. It might be better to perform a type check there so that B instances are accepted whatever. That would require getting a Manifest[B] in your map.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is that if you derive an invariant version from an immutable map, you'll break type safety. For example:

```
val dm = DiotMap(1 -> "abc")
val m: Map[Int, Any] = dm
```

This declaration is valid, because `Map` is covariant. If your collection cannot handle covariance, what will happen when I use `m`?